# How do I select the value of the most recent record (within time-frame) for each case

Tags: spss

How do I select a value of the most recent record (within a specific time frame) with SPSS syntax?
For example: 
I have a database for patients with a chronic bowel disease. Each patient visit to the outpatient clinic is a case in SPSS. So each patient can have multiple cases.

For each visit, multiple FCP results (biomarker in stool) can be entered. 
Now I would like to have a new variable with the FCP result that was most recent to the visit date. However, the date of the FCP result has to be within 60 days prior to the visit and 3 days after the visit, otherwise it would not be valid.

Hopefully anyone could help! I am using SPSS syntax.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow!  It would be easier to understand what you actually need (and help you get it) if you could create a small example of the data with the expected results for the example. Please use the "edit" button for that.